# Misfiring after changing spark plugs

Tags: subaru, sparkplugs, misfire, wrx

2016 WRX Stage 1+BIGSF intake

Dealing with a very annoying issue I CANNOT seem to figure out. Recently I've been tuning my car and figured changing the spark plugs would be a good idea. Ever since I changed the spark plugs (Same exact model number of plugs that were previously in the vehicle, .024 gap) any time I reach about 6+ PSI my engine begins HEAVILY misfiring. It never throws a code. I have tried re-installing spark plugs, a new coil pack, cleaned the MAF a while back, and I cannot get past this problem. My biggest concern is if maybe there is a compression issue because threads got screwed up when I installed the plugs, I am not sure. If it helps today I did a small pull to test and my ignition timing during the pull and misfiring was -16.00? DAM, FBK, and Knock learning are all perfect. I cannot figure out what is going on and its very irritating. Remember, car was working perfectly fine before plugs were swapped!

Comment: If you change the plugs back to the previous ones does the problem go away?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!  You said you DID screw up the threads when putting in the new plugs, or you're wondering if that might be an issue? Usually, if there is misfire (actual misfire) when under boost and not when no boost, the boost is blowing out the spark before it lights the fire.

Comment: Took it to the shop. On installation I cracked cylinder 2's spark plug in 2 places, almost 3 :D they are fixing it now. Thanks everyone!